# Does electric and magnetic fields "Travel" or they just appear in space?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-fields

Suppose that we have a very, very large cubic box (with the edge much larger than the absolute value of $c$) which is completely empty. Now, suppose that we add in there a small sphere with some charge $q$ in one of the vertices. Will the electric field suddenly appear on the entirety of the box or it will "travel", expanding from the vertex at speed $c$? The same question applies to a magnetic field.

I thought about this while playing with some magnets. Suppose that, at the middle point of the box we have a wall, made of some material. If the magnetic field "travels", will the material change the intensity of the field on the other side? When i was playing with 2 magnets today, i noticed that both magnets would attract each other even when separated by a $3\operatorname{cm}$ thick block of wood. However, in a $0.5 \operatorname{cm}$ thick window glass, the magnets would not attract each other. To sum up, here are the two questions:

> Does magnetic/electric field "travel" trough out space?
>
> Does this imply that a material on the way might change the intensity of the field?

Thanks.

Comment: "with the edge much larger than the absolute value of $c$" is a nonsensical statement because edge lengths are not measured in velocity units.

Comment: That's why i said "absolute value".

Comment: That doesn't matter. Saying "absolute value" does nothing to address that problem. The absolute value of a velocity is still a velocity.

Comment: I'm not an native english speaker. In my language when we say "absolute value" thats what we mean: the value, just the numeric value. Thank you for noticing it. I think i should have wrote "numerically bigger".

Comment: Ah, well the English terminology you want is "numeric value". For example, given a value of "-20 m/s", the numeric value is "-20", the unit is "m/s", and the absolute value is "20 m/s". In any case, _none_ of these are valid measurements of an edge length, so the statement is still nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes on both points.

Electromagnetic radiation travels with speed c in the vacuum.
Therefore both components, magnetic and electric travel with this speed.

You cannot perceive it with 'naked eye'  it is too fast to see.